# Having trouble with MarkerWithLabel

Tags: google-maps

I spent a long time searching for the library and finally found it.   However, for the longest time, it still wasn't working.

I finally got it working on one example but not the other and don't know what the difference is:

Working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>MarkerWithLabel Mouse Events</title>
 <style type="text/css">
   .labels {
     color: red;
     background-color: white;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width: 40px;
     border: 2px solid black;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBktMagIayfc1uZIcQu8H91v45qx3shaNI&sensor=false"></script> 
  <script src="./files/js/infobubble.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./files/js/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function initMap() {
     var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
     var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
       zoom: 12,
       center: latLng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });
     var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: homeLatLng,
       draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: true,
       map: map,
       labelContent: "$425K",
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels" // the CSS class for the label
     });
     var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: "Home For Sale"
     });


     var  infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
          maxWidth: 340,
          maxHeight: 165


        });



        infoBubble.addTab('Contact', "<div> <h5 style='text-decoration: underline;'> <B>CONTACT INFORMATION </B></h5> <span style='float:left;'><img src='./images/banner1.jpg' width=100px; height=80px;></img></span> <span style='float:right; font-size: 11.6px; line-height:28px;'> <B>4281 Shooting Park Rd </B> <br/> <B> Peru,IL 61354 </B><br/> <B> 815-223-2800 </B></span>  </div>");



     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) { iw.open(map, this); });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) { log("Click"); });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dblclick", function (e) { log("Double Click"); });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (e) { log("Mouse Over"); });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function (e) { log("Mouse Out"); });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseup", function (e) { log("Mouse Up"); });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mousedown", function (e) { log("Mouse Down"); });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragstart", function (mEvent) { log("Drag Start: " + mEvent.latLng.toString()); });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "drag", function (mEvent) { log("Drag: " + mEvent.latLng.toString()); });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function (mEvent) { log("Drag End: " + mEvent.latLng.toString()); });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
            infoBubble.open(map, marker);
          }
        });
      }


   function log(h) {
     document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += h + "<br />";
   }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="initMap()">
<p>Try interacting with the marker (mouseover, mouseout, click, double-click, mouse down, mouse up, drag) to see a log of events that are fired. Events are fired whether you are interacting with the marker portion or the label portion.</p>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
 <div id="log"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not Working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shooting Park Road Baptist Church</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./files/css/common.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/css/style-ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="./files/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  <script src="./files/js/infobubble.js"></script>
  <script src="./files/js/markerwithlabel.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBktMagIayfc1uZIcQu8H91v45qx3shaNI&sensor=false"></script> 







<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {


$("a.Tag_Nav_Aux").filter(function(){



var daLink = $(this).attr('href').split("?")[0];
var daWindow = "." + window.location.pathname.split("sprbc")[1];

       if (daLink.toLowerCase() == daWindow.toLowerCase())
{

$(this).parent().addClass("activePage");

}
    });

});





<?php include 'header.php';?>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"> Directions </h1>


            <div class="columnWrapper">

                <div class="leftColumn">
<div class="map" style="width: 920px;">


<div style="overflow:auto;height:600px;width:920px;"><div id="map_canvas" style="height:600px;width:920px;"></div><a class="google-map-code" href="http://www.map-embed.com" id="get-map-data">map-embed.com</a><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
map_initialize();
function map_initialize(){
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3378333474912, -89.1608098668396),
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

 var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';

var icon = {
          church: {

            icon: iconBase + 'church_maps.png'
}
          };

        var feature = 
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3378333474912, -89.1608098668396),
            type: 'church'
          };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.3378333474912, -89.1608098668396);





        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: myLatlng,
       map: map,
       labelContent: "Shooting Park Road Baptist Church",
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels" // the CSS class for the label
     });


        var  infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
          maxWidth: 340,
          maxHeight: 165


        });




        infoBubble.addTab('Contact', "<div> <h5 style='text-decoration: underline;'> <B>CONTACT INFORMATION </B></h5> <span style='float:left;'><img src='./images/banner1.jpg' width=100px; height=80px;></img></span> <span style='float:right; font-size: 11.6px; line-height:28px;'> <B>4281 Shooting Park Rd </B> <br/> <B> Peru,IL 61354 </B><br/> <B> 815-223-2800 </B></span>  </div>");
        infoBubble.addTab('Schedule', "<div> <h5 style='text-decoration: underline;'><B> SCHEDULE </B> </h5><br/><?php  

$month = date('n');



if ($month == 1 || $month == 2 || $month == 7)
{

?>

<B>Sunday School: 9:30 am<br> Sunday Morning: 10:30 am<br> Sunday Evening: 1:00 pm <br> Wednesday  Morning:  10:00 am <br> Kings Kids:  6:30 pm <br> Wednesday  Evening:  7:00 pm </B>
<?php


}

else
{
?>
   <B>Sunday School: 9:30 am<br> Sunday Morning: 10:30 am<br> Sunday Evening: 6:30 pm   <br>Kings Kids:  6:30 pm <br>Wednesday Evening:  7:00 pm </B><?php
}
?><br/><br/></div>");



        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
            infoBubble.open(map, marker);
          }
        });
      }

</script>


                    </div>


<?php include 'footer.php';?>


            </body>




</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/printercu/google-maps-utility-library-v3-read-only/tree/master/markerwithlabel

Comment: I have that one.  It's not working.

Comment: It keeps saying MapLabel is not defined.  google is not defined.

Comment: I was able to get it working in one example but not the other.    It doesn't seem to be working with InfoBubble.